# angular ng-change doesn't update website

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular 1.5.7 (can't really understand angular2, seem way harder to me). I am using simple gettext module to translate elements on website.

```
var ntsvApp = angular.module('ntsvApp', ['gettext']);
ntsvApp.controller("ntsvCtrl", function($scope, gettextCatalog){
    gettextCatalog.currentLanguage = 'en';
    $scope.languages = ['pl', 'en', 'ru'];
    $scope.lang = 'en';
    $scope.changeLang = function(){
        gettextCatalog.currentLanguage = $scope.lang;
    };

});
```

if i set gettextCatalog.currentLanguage to whatever, it works and displays correct language. But when i use ng-change on select, it doesn't update website.

```
<li><select ng-model="lang" ng-options="lang for lang in languages" ng-change="changeLang()"></select></li>
```

where is the problem?

Comment: Is the function actually being called? Have you tried a `console.log()`?

Comment: Are you using routes? If so have you tried reloading the route after the change? Could you make a Plunker for this?

Comment: Provide link to `gettext` module docs. A demo that reproduces problem would also help

Comment: https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/mnkZMjzdHgJ1Z1rs24lr/